# Find the difference between two strings of uneven length in python

Tags: python, string, for-loop

```
a = 'abcdfjghij'
b = 'abcdfjghi'
```

`Output : j`

```
def diff(a, b):
    string=''
    for val in a:
        if val not in b:
            string=val
    return string

a = 'abcdfjghij'
b = 'abcdfjghi'
print(diff(a,b))
```

This code returns an empty string.
Any solution for this?

Comment: There are no characters in `a` that aren't contained in `b`, so an empty string is the expected result here.  To get `"j"` as the result, you would have to compare the counts of each character in both strings, rather than just their existence.

Comment: I understand your approach but I am not able to come up with a solution.

Comment: When you searched SO with `python find difference between two strings` did any of those Q&A's solve your problem?

Comment: @wwii The answer is no. It was important to me to have a solution without using any packages. Moreover, every solution in SO was for the same string length

Comment: How would you do this by hand? Describe the steps you would take to do this yourself.

Comment: You cannot use any modules in the standard library?

Comment: @wwi Yes, can't use any modules.

Comment: Even if string `b` is shorter than string `a`, do you need to know if there are characters in `b` that are not in `a`? Expected result for `a = 'abcdfjghij'` and `b = 'xbcdfjghi'`?

Answer (score 1):

`collections.Counter` from the standard library can be used to model multi-sets, so it keeps track of repeated elements. It's a subclass of `dict` which is performant and extends its functionality for counting purposes. To find differences between two strings you can **mimic** a *symmetric difference* between sets.

```
from collections import Counter

a = 'abcdfjghij'
b = 'abcdfjghi'

ca = Counter(a)
cb = Counter(b)

diff = (cb-ca)+(ca-cb) # symmetric difference

print(diff)
#Counter({'j': 1})
```

Comment: This is a reasonable solution, but I am looking for one without any built-in modules.

Comment: then make a inverse ingeneering of this answer, the goal is still the same... mimic a symmetric difference. So, how should you introduced a multi-set?

Answer (score 0):

**updated**

But you have j twice in a. So the first time it sees j it looks at b and sees a j, all good. For the second j it looks again and still sees a j, all good.
Are you wanting to check if each letter is the same as the other letter in the same sequence, then you should try this:

```
a = 'abcdfjghij'
b = 'abcdfjghi'

def diff(a, b):
  if len(a)>len(b):
    smallest_len = len(b)
    for index, value in enumerate(a[:smallest_len]):
      if a[index] != b[index]:
        print(f'a value {a[index]} at index {index} does not match b value {b[index]}')
    if len(a) == len(b):
      pass
    else:
      print(f'Extra Values in A Are {a[smallest_len:]}')
  else:
    smallest_len = len(a)
    for index, value in enumerate(b[:smallest_len]):
      if a[index] != b[index]:
        print(f'a value {a[index]} at index {index} does not match b value {b[index]}')
    if len(a) == len(b):
      pass
    else:
      print(f'Extra Values in B Are {b[smallest_len:]}')
  

diff(a, b)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, the input you have taken and the input I have posted are different. Could you please recheck it?

Comment: Your input ```a = 'abcdfjghij'
b = 'abcdfjhi'```
My input : ```a = 'abcdfjghij'
b = 'abcdfjghi'```

Comment: There's ```g``` in both a and b.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of ... when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). [Why not upload images of code on SO  ...?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).  [You should not post code as an image because:...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755).

Comment: Answer updated.  wwii I included both images and code.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, there are 2 differences between the 2 strings :
The letter g and j.
I tested your code and it returns g because all the other letters from are in b:

```py
a = 'abcdfjghij'
b = 'abcdfjhi'

def diff(a, b):
    string=''
    for val in a:
        if val not in b:
            string=val
    return string

print(diff(a,b))
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste them as text then format as code (select and type ctrl-k)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of ... when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). [Why not upload images of code on SO  ...?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).  [You should not post code as an image because:...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755).

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to know exactly what you want based on your question. Like should

```
'abc'
'efg'
```

return 'abc' or 'efg' or is there always just going to be one character added?

Here is a solution that accounts for multiple characters being different but still might not give your exact output.

```
def diff(a, b):
    string = ''
    
    if(len(a) >= len(b)):
        longString = a
        shortString = b
    else:
        longString = b
        shortString = a
    for i in range(len(longString)):
        if(i >= len(shortString) or longString[i] != shortString[i]):
            string += longString[i]
    return string

a = 'abcdfjghij'
b = 'abcdfjghi'
print(diff(a,b))
```

if one string just has one character added and i could be anywhere in the string you could change

```
string += longString[i]
```

to

```
string = longString[i]
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work if the input is ```a = 'abaa'
b = 'aaa'```
Even if I change ```string += longString[i]``` to ```string = longString[i]```

Comment: try adding a break after `string = longString[i] `

Comment: Yes, it did work. But what is the input is ```a = 'abcaa'
b = 'aaa'```

Comment: So if the problem is one string has added characters you could keep track of how many different characters you have flagged and add that number to `i` when accessing the characters for the long string, (this means you wouldnt want the break)

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctyl your question is:

> "given 2 strings of different length, how can I find the characters
> that are different between them?"

So judging by your example, this implies you want either the characters that are only present in 1 of the strings and not on the other, or characters that might be repeated and which count is different in between the two strings.

Here's a simple solution (maybe not the most efficient one), but one that's short and does not require any extra packages:

**UPDATED: **

```
a = 'abcdfjghij'
b = 'abcdfjghi' 

dict_a = dict( (char, a.count(char)) for char in a)
dict_b = dict( (char, b.count(char)) for char in b)

idx_longest = [dict_a, dict_b].index(max([dict_a, dict_b], key = len))

results = [ k for (k,v) in [dict_a, dict_b][idx_longest].items() if k not in [dict_a, dict_b][1-idx_longest].keys() or v!=[dict_a, dict_b][1-idx_longest][k] ]

print(results)
 > ['j']
```

or you can try with other pair of strings such as

```
a = 'abcaa'
b = 'aaa'

print(results)
 > ['b', 'c']
```

as 'a' is in both string an equal number of times.

Comment: Good solution but there's a slight error. If the input is ```a = 'abcdfjghij'
b = 'abcdfjghi'``` The result will be an empty string.

Comment: you are right, when both dicts are the same length this doesnt give the right answer. Thanks for the correction. I updated the answer. Should work now, cheers